# After saving nvidia-setting into xorg.conf, main monitor got disabled

Tags: drivers, nvidia, xorg, multiple-monitors

I've had this problem for a while that when I try to save nvidia setting into xorg.conf 
my main monitor disables.
process:
I open the nvidia-setting then go to second monitor setting, click on advanced and check the "Force Full Composition Pipeline" then try to save the setting.
after a reboot my prime display goes black with back-lights on
and gdm would not detect it.
[image][image][image][image][image]
here is xorg.conf:

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 440.64

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load           "dbe"
    Load           "extmod"
    Load           "type1"
    Load           "freetype"
    Load           "glx"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    # HorizSync source: edid, VertRefresh source: edid
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Ancor Communications Inc ASUS VC239"
    HorizSync       24.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     50.0 - 75.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce GTX 1650"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "Stereo" "0"
    Option         "nvidiaXineramaInfoOrder" "DFP-2"
    Option         "metamodes" "nvidia-auto-select +1920+0 {ForceCompositionPipeline=On, ForceFullCompositionPipeline=On}"
    Option         "SLI" "Off"
    Option         "MultiGPU" "Off"
    Option         "BaseMosaic" "off"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

$ ubuntu-drivers list

```
nvidia-driver-440, (kernel modules provided by linux-modules-nvidia-440-generic-hwe-20.04)
nvidia-driver-435, (kernel modules provided by nvidia-dkms-435)
backport-iwlwifi-dkms, (kernel modules provided by backport-iwlwifi-dkms)
```

System info

```
System:    Host: ubuntu-pc Kernel: 5.4.0-28-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 
           Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
CPU:       Topology: Quad Core model: Intel Core i5-9300H bits: 64 type: MT MCP L2 cache: 8192 KiB 
           Speed: 1300 MHz min/max: 800/2400 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 1300 2: 1300 3: 1300 4: 1300 5: 1300 6: 1300 7: 1300 
           8: 1300 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel UHD Graphics 630 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA TU117M [GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q] driver: nvidia v: 435.21 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: modesetting,nvidia unloaded: fbdev,nouveau,vesa 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1920x1080~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 1650/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 435.21
```